# Play framework - unit testing controllers with dependencies

Tags: java, unit-testing, playframework, mocking, playframework-2.1

I am in a process of writing web application that uses Play framework (2.1.1 version).

I wrote my first, very simple, controller and I wanted to unit test it.

The thing is, because Play controllers are all static I am wondering what is the correct way to mock out dependencies, for example, lets take some `MyService`:

```
private static MyService myService = new MyServiceImpl();
```

I am using this kind of initialization in my application to deliver controller dependencies.

Now, if I would want to mock out my dependency I could create static method that sets the `myService` field to mocked out implementation of `MyService`.

Is this the way it is done in play framework application that is written in Java? Or maybe there is some more "idiomatic" way to do this kind of thing in Play framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to achieve something like that is documented on http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaInjection .

On https://github.com/guillaumebort/play20-spring-demo is a demo of a Play Spring project.

With `play.Play.isTest()` you can check if you are in test mode. It is documented on http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.1/java/play/Play.html .